# ¿Como se llaman este tipo de variables "<TMPL_VAR NAME=JAVAURL> " y como se utilizan?

Tags: javascript, html, web, perl

estoy trabajando sobre un sistema hecho en perl, javascript y html, pero me tope con esta variable:

```
<TMPL_VAR NAME=JAVAURL>
```

> `<script language="javascript" src="<TMPL_VAR NAME=JAVAURL>/Functions.js"></script>`

Nunca las habia utilizado, alguien podría ayudarme a darme una idea de como se utilizan este tipo de variables?

Se los agredezco!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son marcas especiales para usarlas con el módulo HTML::Template de Perl:

https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información! Me ayudó a comprenderlo mejor!